# SQL Developer returning different date than SQL Plus command line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have the following script in SQL Developer, but it seems to be returning an invalid date when it is run in SQL Plus command line.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
   yesterday varchar2(30);
   tz_yesterday varchar2(30);
BEGIN
   select sysdate - 1 into yesterday from dual;
   select cast(yesterday as timestamp WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE) into tz_yesterday from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line(yesterday);
   dbms_output.put_line(tz_yesterday);
END;
```

This is the output given by SQL Developer, which is correct:

```
10-OCT-18
10-OCT-18 12.00.00.000000 AM
```

This is what I get in SQL Plus

```
SQL> l
  1  DECLARE
  2    g_vendor_id NUMBER;
  3    g_product_id NUMBER;
  4    yesterday varchar2(30);
  5    tz_yesterday varchar2(30);
  6    g_user_id NUMBER;
  7   BEGIN
  8    select sysdate - 1 into yesterday from dual;
  9    select cast(yesterday as timestamp WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE) into tz_yesterday from dual;
 10  dbms_output.put_line(yesterday);
 11  dbms_output.put_line(tz_yesterday);
 12* End;
SQL> /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Can someone explain the discrepancy here?

Comment: You are relying on the evil implicit data type conversion and most probably your error is caused by different NLS settings between SQL Developer and sqlplus

Comment: Is there a way to set the date dynamically without relying on type conversion?

Comment: `yesterday` and `tz_yesterday` are not strings, use proper data types.

Comment: your query is working fine in oracle 12c using sql developer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't store date or timestamp values in varchar variables, always use the correct data types:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
   yesterday date;
   tz_yesterday timestamp with local time zone;
BEGIN
   yesterday := sysdate - 1;
   tz_yesterday := cast(yesterday as timestamp WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE);
   dbms_output.put_line(yesterday);
   dbms_output.put_line(tz_yesterday);
END;
/
```